# How to have specific prices for some particular pin codes in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am having a problem with my woocommerce store, I want to have lower product prices for some pin codes but I am unable to find a way of doing that.
If anyone knows how to do that please help.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/pincode-based-product-price-woocommerce/